# Read.table isn't interpreting the number of columns in a table correctly

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to mass introduce tables with 24 columns and only one row.

These tables are in a text file outputted using the print() function from a different R code and a bash script- I do this because I have to output 1000s of these tables at once, and want to be able to quickly scan them. The output, as mentioned above, has many columns but one row, and when it's in a text file, the table spills onto multiple lines.

Here is an example of a table modified for simplicity- in reality there a few extra columns that result in more lines, but all the same, there is only one row and each column name is "columnx" (no repeating names in the real thing.)

[image: Example of a similar table]

One of the ways I've introduced the table into R using read.table and then setting "header" and "fill" to TRUE. (I've also fiddled with readLines, readCVS, scan etc. but read.table is the best outcome so far.) However, when I do so, it only interprets the first set line of column headers as columns. Everything below, including the other columns and column names, are rows belonging to those columns. So in case of the picture above, only columns1:17 are included as column headers.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on where to start to get around this before I attempt to just read it in with readLines and parsing it. I am trying to find solutions to change the output as well so that the text file produces all the columns on one line.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any control over the other R code? An approach that relies on `print()` and writing that output to file is going to give you something different based on the width of the console each time the other script is run. it would be better to be able to use `write.csv` or another function designed to write data to file in the other script, which would make reading the data in in this script easy.

Comment: I'm not able to try anything on this without sample data, and I'm not going to try to transcribe this to something usable. Please don't include images of data/code/errors when the (top two lines of the) raw file should be just as easy to include in a code-block in your question.

Comment: @r2evans sorry about that! I thought that the code-block was only for scripts of code but now that I'm reading up on it I can see that I was ignorant on that and how it's considered pretty bad form lol. Thanks for the feedback and letting me know. :)

Comment: The "code block" is great for anything that benefits from fixed-width fonts, data is one such example.

Comment: @CalumYou Thanks for the help! I originally wasn't sure about write.csv because I need to output 1000s of these tables at once, which is what I used the print and bash script for, and I wasn't sure if I could do that with write.csv, but I will look more into that because that sounds like it would solve my issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use data that was temporarily available in your question:

```r
txt <- "column1      column122   column3   column4   column5   column6 
 27013443     10.33132 6.622399e-10 2701000   10.33132 6.622399e-10 
column12     column123   column44  column55    column67   column18
 10.33132  6.622399e-10      0       2.3        0            1.1  "

spl <- strsplit(txt, "[\n\r]+")[[1]]
ind1 <- seq(1, length(spl), by = 2)
ind2 <- seq(2, length(spl), by = 2)
out <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = c(
  paste(spl[ind1], collapse = " "),
  paste(spl[ind2], collapse = " ")
))
out
#    column1 column122      column3 column4  column5      column6 column12    column123 column44 column55 column67 column18
# 1 27013443  10.33132 6.622399e-10 2701000 10.33132 6.622399e-10 10.33132 6.622399e-10        0      2.3        0      1.1
```

If you're having a problem with the amount of blank-space between each column, then you can preemptively reduce those gaps, converting into a CSV:

```r
txt2 <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", ",", txt)
spl2 <- strsplit(txt2, "[\n\r]+")[[1]]
ind1 <- seq(1, length(spl), by = 2)
ind2 <- seq(2, length(spl), by = 2)
out2 <- read.csv(text = c(
  paste(spl2[ind1], collapse = " "),
  paste(spl2[ind2], collapse = " ")
))
out
#    column1 column122      column3 column4  column5      column6 column12    column123 column44 column55 column67 column18
# 1 27013443  10.33132 6.622399e-10 2701000 10.33132 6.622399e-10 10.33132 6.622399e-10        0      2.3        0      1.1
```

Comment: user13097399, does this address your issue? If not, perhaps you can fill in where I'm missing something.

Comment: @r2evans- sorry for the late reply- thank you very much for your help! I will try this out right now and let you know :)